# adding store data on Extjs grid(3)

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3, gridpanel

I have a jsonstore which contains about 500 records, and every time I add more data to store, I call `grid.getView().refresh()` to bind data on gridpanel, but it's taking 5-6 seconds and it's also hanging the browser.

Is there any other way to bind the gridpanel or refresh the gridpanel faster?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just add the results on the store's load method?  I was thinking something like:

```
grid.store.load({add:true, params: your_params_here});
```

See load method's api: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load

Comment: If you create the grid w/ a store property like:
    `var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        ...
        store: some_store,
        ...
     });`
it should refresh the grid whenever the store changes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the whole stuff is done within the UI thread. Therefore the speed depends on the browser: Chrome will most likely be very fast while an IE7 or IE8 are noticeable slower.

Have you already taken a look at firebug's (or IE's, or Chrome's) profiler to see where most of the CPU time is spent? I wonder if it's the row-refreshing or the layouting.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have large and growing data, how about using buffered grid with pagination ?

[extjs pagination display on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awCBz.png)

May be this link would help you. [extjs grid with pagination](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?257351-Create-Buffered-Grid-in-Extjs-3-4-0)